# What is this " var1 = Math.Ceiling(hours / (40.00M * 4.3M));"

Tags: c#

Anyone know what the C# "M" syntax means?

```
var1 = Math.Ceiling(hours / (40.00M * 4.3M));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

M is the suffix for Decimal. Stands for "money" I assume.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 8):

it means that the number is a `decimal` type.

Answer (score 5):

The default interpretation of 40.00 will be a double with the value 40.00, just like the default interpretation of 40 is an int.

If you want a decimal or a long instead, you add can append the M (decimal) and L suffixes (long).